# Given a string of even length, return the first half. So the string "WooHoo" yields "Woo"

Tags: java

This is what I have so far:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = scan.nextLine();

    int x = str.length();
    int y = str.charAt(x/2);
    System.out.println(str.substring(y, x-1));
```

For some reason when I run this it's giving me an error.
Please HELP!

I'm still a beginner in this, and I only know how to use the basics in Java.
I don't know how to use arrays and other advanced stuff.
If someone can tell me how to solve this problem in the simplest way possible that would be great!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Btw I didn't write the class and main here because there is something wrong in the code, so I couldn't post it.

Comment: What's wrong with `System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() / 2));`?

Comment: `System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() / 2));`

Comment: You should probably post the error as well.

Comment: Oh right! My mistake. I thought the question wants the second half of the string. Can I still do it using the substring method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int y = str.charAt(x/2);` is not required, actually return character at mid position.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        int x = str.length();
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, x/2)); // return part of full string starting from index 0 to mid index
    }
```

**Output**

```
WooHoo
Woo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: even length string always

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String str = scan.nextLine();

int x = str.length()/2;
System.out.println(str.substring(0, x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `str.charAt(x/2)` returns the middle character of the string and when you are storing it to an integer it will covert to its ascii value, which you dont want.

You can do like :

```
str.substring(0,(str.length())/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like one of the problems from [codingbat.com](http://codingbat.com/prob/p172267), the solution is pretty simple:

```
return str.substring(0, str.length() / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str="";
    Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
    str=S.nextLine();
    int length=str.length();
    if(length%2==0)
    {
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, length-(length/2)));
    }
    else
        System.out.println(" ");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.